# What keeps the BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync method from completing?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, background-service, ihostedservice

I have just created a Worker Service using the standard Visual Studio template. In the Worker class if I remove the `while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested){...}` wrapper and run the app, ExecuteAsync never completes. If I add `return` to the end of the method, again it doesn't complete.

Can anyone explain what keeps the method alive?

I wonder why in the code below that `ExecuteAsync` doesn't just complete and tear down my `FileSystemWatcher`? I can just keep triggering the watcher until pressing Ctrl+C which cancels the token and stops the whole application.

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) =>
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

                    _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_settings.Value.FolderToWatch, "Transactions_????????.xml")
                    {
                        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName
                    };
                    _watcher.Created += FileCreated;
                    _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                    _logger.LogInformation("Monitoring folder '{watchedFolder}' for file drops...", _settings.Value.FolderToWatch);
                }
                catch (Exception e) when (False(() => _logger.LogCritical(e,"Fatal error.")))
                {
                    throw;
                }

            });
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Updated with code sample.

Answer (score 1):

A [BackgroundService](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs#L49) doesn't care if your ExecuteAsync method completes before shutdown. It only cares that your service stops before the server can stop.

I would suggest that you implement a job queue, add to the queue in your `FileCreated` method, and process the queue in your ExecuteAsync method. Returning when stoppingToken is cancelled. That way you can block the server shutdown until the current file change has been processed, or pass on the cancel token.

And don't forget to Dispose() your FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: Ah, your last comment helped me clear up my incorrectly stated question. `ExecuteAsync` is in fact completing. But my `Worker` class is still in memory. So my private field reference `_watcher` still holds a reference to my `FileSystemWatcher` which was not being disposed until the application was stopped.